# Is the trunk of this honeysuckle in danger of being strangled?

Tags: plant-care, honeysuckle

You are looking at a rare specimen of estimated 50 years old honeysuckle: *(the honeysuckle is in the foreground; there is a high dark green conifer in the background, but it is not essential for this question)*

[image]

It grows from just a small piece of soil, surrounded by a brick wall and a concrete patio:

[image]

The trunk has a formidable size (20cm diameter). However, it interacts with a decorative iron fence: *(there is 3/4 of the full circle of iron around the center of the decorative area, the central part of the spiral - this is partially visible on photos, try to spot a black metal curved piece right in the center of the ornament, it 'hugs' the curved double trunk)*

[image]

[image]

Is the trunk of this honeysuckle in danger of being strangled?

The plant seems otherwise healthy and vigorous.

Comment: Leave it alone.  If it has lived for 50 years it knows better than anyone what it wants!  What it needs!  Wow.  Is this on your property?

Answer (score 6):

I don't think it's in danger of being strangled. Like trees do, if there's an obstruction, the woody parts will envelop and surround whatever the obstruction is, if they have to, but, being a vine, this plant has grown branches in other directions, which is not a choice a tree trunk can easily make.

If this one is as old as you say, it's more than geriatric anyway - average lifespan for Lonicera is reputed to be around 20 years, depending on variety, so as the gridwork hasn't strangled it when it was simply mature, it's unlikely to now. The wall is at much more risk than the plant... the roots have likely caused the cracks in the wall visible in the photograph.

Comment: After 50 years, I'd be very careful not to mess with that lower 'trunk' at all. The plant's made it this far, but it might well object to disturbances of its bottom.

Comment: This plant's not the only thing that would object to such disturbances... sorry, couldn't resist, it is crimbo after all!

Comment: The question is about the plant, and not about the wall.

Comment: I think dynamics of this trunk shape is different than you suggest. The plant didn't take one direction in early years, and then, after several years, being the vine, decided to go in another direction, and again the same after next five years. The path of the trunk IMHO was determined in the first or the second year max, so the plant did not have 'choice' to go left or right after that, as you claim. But the trunk (or trunks) got wider and wider.

Comment: The only thing I would allow myself to do would be to cut off all the tiny little branches, growths.  The plant made a choice based on light. Plain and simple.  She meant the wall would go before this honeysuckle. I'd relish this plant, take pictures, talk to it (grins, seriously).  What a treat.  Bamboo is correct, 50 years is a massive anomaly.  Such a major treat!